# Replace rootViewController behind a modal view

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uikit

With the following code I'm able to change the `rootViewController` behind a modal view :

```
let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let signupVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SignupNavigationController") as! UINavigationController
let landingPageVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LandingPage") as! LandingPageViewController

presentViewController(signupVC, animated: true, completion: {
   UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate?.window??.rootViewController = landingPageVC
   UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate?.window??.sendSubviewToBack(landingPageVC.view)
})
```

When I close my modal view controller it's the previous rootViewController that is displayed (only during the animation). Then my new view controller is displayed properly.

Any idea how I could prevent this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering to myself,

The view I can see during the modal animation is something like a snapshot. I found out that the view is not visible in Xcode's view hierarchy debugger, thus the view is not present in the viewController tree.

To refresh this snapshot I had to set the `modalPresentationStyle` to `.OverFullScreen`

```
    myModalViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .OverFullScreen
```